# SP 2013 : Error in Get list by name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, custom-list

I have a list named `sysCurrentUserInstance` on my *dev SP server* and *test SP server* too. When I call (simplified) command:

```
var list = context.web.Lists["sysCurrentUserInstance"]
```

I've got relevant object on my *dev server*, but exception on *test server*. 
On *test server* only call with **Current User Instance** list name works fine, 
why ?

Below is my schema details:

[Source list schema](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwx1__eslZTCc0M2OXdqemo0akE/view?usp=sharing)

[Dest list schema](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwx1__eslZTCUHBfWnlXMEZxMW8/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you very much
Marian

Comment: when you go to list settings, is the list url the same in both lists?

Comment: `context.web.Lists["List Title"]` needs the Title of the list.

Comment: @Gwny http://dtobstaranie:45188/lokality/SEVODEV2/Lists/sysCurrentUserInstance/AllItems.aspx = source; http://bspgv_p1:28896/Lists/sysCurrentUserInstance/AllItems.aspx = destination

Comment: and the title of the list?

Comment: @Gwny : Title depends on language current user settings. In General list settings->Name = **Current User Instance** on both test & dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the methode GetList(url) or Lists[GUID] instead of Lists["listName"].

```
var list = context.web.GetList("/mySite/Lists/sysCurrentUserInstance");
```

To quote [Best Practices for SP OM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949(v=office.12).aspx):

> You can retrieve an SPList object from the SPWeb.Lists property by
>   using the list's GUID or display name as an indexer. Using
>   SPWeb.Lists[GUID] and SPWeb.GetList(strURL) is always preferable to
>   using SPWeb.Lists[strDisplayName]. Using the GUID is preferable
>   because it is unique, permanent, and requires only a single database
>   lookup. The display name indexer retrieves the names of all the lists
>   in the site and then does a string comparison with them. If you have a
>   list URL instead of a GUID, you can use the GetList() method to look
>   up the list's GUID in the content database before retrieving the list.

Comment: I know, what are you telling me... I no, that my code snipet is not write in good manner... (I have, no GUID, no url...) But back to my question: why I've got a different results on servers ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your list **internal name** in both environment.
or try another way

```
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("ListInternalName");
```

Comment: the internal name is not the title as far as I know

Comment: @ankur no such a method. Sorry - I am using server object model, no client, rest and js api.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `var list = context.web.Lists["sysCurrentUserInstance"]` uses the title of the list. If this can vary, this is not a good method to use then.

If the list url inside of the site will not change you can use

```
 string listUrl = "/sites/sitecollection/subsite/Lists/Announcements";
 SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx

Comment: I have the same Title. I cannot use url. Thank you.

Comment: why can't you use the urL?